# How to change the result of IAudioClient->GetMixFormat() method?

Tags: windows, audio

In normal case, call IAudioClient->GetMixFormat() method on a device which only have stereo playback device will get default audio format on share mode which is 2 channels format.

But for some reason, I need to let all applicationes on this device get 6/8 channels format when they call IAudioClient->GetMixFormat().

Here is a section of decription of IAudioClient->GetMixFormat() method on MSDN website.

> The mix format is the format that the audio engine uses internally for digital processing of shared-mode streams. This format is not necessarily a format that the audio endpoint device supports.

Answer (score 0):

It is the mix format for shared usage mode when applications play audio [in compatible formats] and system mixes everything together for resulting playback stream. The format may be altered via Control Panel, see screenshot in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336308/868014):

[image]

Not every device will offer 5.1 and 7.1 options though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Actually, what I want to implement is to force IAudioClient->GetMixFormat() method return 7.1 information even if this is a stereo playback device.
After that, in format neogotiation, audio engine will ask SFX APO if it supports 7.1 input instead of ask SFX APO if it supports stereo input.